# syntax error, unexpected '{' php drupal modul

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\atins\drupal\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module on line 3

my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){ 
  if($form_id == "webform-client-form-57--3"){ 
    $form["webform-component-email-address"]["#default_value"] = "BLAH BLAH";
  }
}
```

**I cant figure out whats wrong. :/**

Comment: You are missing a `function` in front of all this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've left out the `function` declaration:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){ 
  if($form_id == "webform-client-form-57--3"){ 
    $form["webform-component-email-address"]["#default_value"] = "BLAH BLAH";
  }  
}
```

Another small note, you should be passing in `$form_state` by reference (`&$form_state`), just in case you plan to use it in your hook (see [`hook_form_alter()` documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)).

Answer (score 3):

There's missing `function` keyword in front of your... function.

Answer (score 3):

You need the keyword `function` before your function name